# Why is this offset not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set an offset so that I can list all blog posts, excluding the most recent ones which have their own box.

Here's the code:

```
@postlist = Post.where(:approved => true).offset(4).all
```

It just lists everything though and completely disregards the offset? any ideas?

Comment: Exactly the same @vucko

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: sqlite @FrederickCheung

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite doesn't support offset with no limit (see [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html) for what a sqlite select statement can contain)

As a workaround you can pass a very large limit or a negative limit.